# Neural ODE definition of derivative $\frac{d L}{dz(t)}$ (adjoint)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chain-rule, neural-networks

The authors of [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366) (NeuRIPS 2018 best paper award), propose to model machine learning problems with an ODE

$$ \dot z(t) = f(t, z(t), \theta) \quad{\text{s.t.}}\quad z(t_0)=z_0$$

where $f$ is e.g. a neural network with parameters $\theta$. The Gradient with respect to a loss function $L$ is computed via the adjoint method:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d L}{d\theta} = -\int_{t_1}^{t_0}a(t)^T\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} d t
\quad\text{where}\quad
\dot a(t) = -a(t)^T\frac{\partial f}{\partial z},\,
a(t_1)=\frac{dL}{dz(t_1)}
\end{aligned}$$

I have a problem with interpreting the adjoint state $a(t)$. The paper claims that the adjoint state is given by $a(t)=\frac{dL}{dz(t)}$. However, let's consider the [simple example$\,\dot z = w z,\, z(t_0)=z_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608614) with solution $\hat z(t) := z^*(t;t_0, z_0, w) = e^{w (t-t_0)}z_0$ and loss function $L(w)=\frac{1}{2}|\hat z(t_1) - z_1|^2$. Then, solving the adjoint system yields:

$$\left.\begin{aligned}
\dot a(t) &= - a(t)^T \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = -w \cdot  a(t) 
\\ a(t_1) &= \frac{d L }{d z(t_1)} = \hat z(t_1) - z_1
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace\implies a(t) = e^{-w(t-t_1)}(\hat z(t_1) - z_1)
$$

I veried that this is indeed correct, integrating $-\int_{t_1}^{t_0} a(t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}dt$ gives the correct derivative $\frac{dL}{dw}$.

Plugging back the solution $\hat z$ of the ODE yields $a(t)=e^{-w(t-t_1)}(e^{w (t_1-t_0)}z_0 - z_1)$ (I think I got all the signs correct here.)

However, I do not see how to mechanistically form the derivative $\frac{d L}{dz(t)}$ directly and arrive at the same result.

If we interpret $\frac{dL}{dz(t)}$ as $\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{1}{2}|z-z_1|^2)\big|_{z=\hat z(t)}$ we get $\hat z(t)-z_1$, which is unequal to $a(t)$. So how is $\frac{dL}{dz(t)}$ formally defined, such that it ends up equal ? The paper never explains this.

Secondly, I would like to know if there is a more direct way to derive the adjoint equation. I am aware of the author's derivation in the appendix as well as the derivation via [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle). The first one appears unmotived whilst the second one for some reason requires the consideration of an optimization problem, when all we want to do is compute a derivative.

Answer (score 3):

As a first result to resolve the conundrum. Let $\hat z(t)=z^*(t, t_0, z_0, \theta)$, with fixed initial condition $t_0, z_0$, then it appears that the (in)correct interpretation of the term is given by:

$$\begin{alignedat}{3}
\text{incorrect:}&&  \frac{dL}{dz(t)} &\overset{\text{def}}{=} \frac{d}{d\hat z(t)}L\big(\underbrace{z^{*}(t;t_0,z_0,\theta)}_{=\hat z(t)}\big) &&\overset{\text{def}}{=}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}L(z)\Big|_{z=\hat z(t)}
\\ \text{correct:}&& \frac{dL}{dz(t)} &\overset{\text{def}}{=} \frac{d}{d\hat z(t)}L\big(z^{*}(t_1;t,\hat z(t),\theta\big) &&\overset{\text{def}}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}L\big(z^*(t_1; t,z, \theta)\big)\Big|_{z=\hat  z(t)}
\end{alignedat}$$

We can observe that in the example scenario

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}L(z)\Big|_{z=\hat z(t)} 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big[\frac{1}{2}\|z-z_1\|_2^2\Big]\Bigg|_{z=\hat z(t)}
\\&= (z-z_1)\Big|_{z=\hat z(t)} 
\\&= \hat z(t)-z_1   = e^{w(t_-t_0)}z_0 - z_1{\huge\color{red}{↯}}
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}L(z^*(t_1; t,z, \theta))\Big|_{z=\hat z(t)}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big[\frac{1}{2}\|e^{w(t_1-t)}z-z_1\|_2^2\Big]\Bigg|_{z=\hat z(t)} 
\\&= e^{w(t_1-t)}(e^{w(t_1-t)}z-z_1)\Big|_{z=\hat z(t)}
\\&= e^{w(t_1-t)}(e^{w(t_1-t)}\hat z(t)-z_1)
\\&=e^{w(t_1-t)}(e^{w(t_1-t)}e^{w(t-t_0)}z_0-z_1) 
\\&=e^{w(t_1-t)}(e^{w(t_1-t_0)}z_0-z_1)
\\&=e^{w(t_1-t)}(\hat z(t_1)-z_1) {\huge\color{green}{\checkmark}}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Could you please also look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725191/derivatives-of-ode-trajectories-w-r-t-function-values-at-specific-time-points ?